# Conservar 000 en una suma

Tags: php, html

Tengo el siguiente código donde obtengo el `MAX` de un código, pero este código es un `String`. A este `MAX` lo separo en dos para sacarle las 3 primeras iniciales que son letras y en los numeros para poder sumarle 1 a los numeros.

```
    $query  = "SELECT MAX(CodMaquina) FROM Maestro_Maquinas WHERE Centro_Costo = '$centro_costo'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $row    = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

    $numbers = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $row[0]);
    $letters = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z]/', '', $row[0]);
      $sumnumbers = $numbers+1;
    $codmaquina = $letters.$sumnumbers;
    echo   $codmaquina;
```

El valor inicial del `row[0]` es `ELA0045` pero el  resultado es `ELA46`. Como puedo conservar los `00` o aplicar otra formular para sumar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu variable $numbers contiene la cadena de texto que se corresponde con el número.

Por tanto, lo único que debes hacer es usar la función [str_pad](http://php.net/manual/es/function.str-pad.php):

```
$query  = "SELECT MAX(CodMaquina) FROM Maestro_Maquinas WHERE Centro_Costo = '$centro_costo'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$row    = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

$numbers = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $row[0]);
$letters = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z]/', '', $row[0]);
$sumnumbers = $numbers+1;
$sumnumbers = str_pad($sumnumbers, strlen($numbers), '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
$codmaquina = $letters.$sumnumbers;
echo   $codmaquina;
```

Espero que te sirva. Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la función [**`sprintf`**](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_sprintf.asp) que con este formato, siempre mantendrá los 4 dígitos que necesitas, agregando 0's a la izquierda cuando estas cifras estén vacías:

```
$sumnumbers = sprintf("%04s", $numbers+1);
```

Finalmente tu código quedaría así:

```
$query  = "SELECT MAX(CodMaquina) FROM Maestro_Maquinas WHERE Centro_Costo = '$centro_costo'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$row    = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

$numbers = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $row[0]);
$letters = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z]/', '', $row[0]);
echo   $numbers;
$sumnumbers = sprintf('%04s', $numbers+1);
$codmaquina = $letters.$sumnumbers;
echo   $codmaquina;
```